# Sort or search text messages by date

Tags: sms

How do I search and or sort individual text messages by date/time?

I am using an AT&T Samsung Galaxy S5.

Answer (score 0):

export your message conversation (like a backup) with that particular person as a CSV file excel spreadsheet after that u can just sort by date in excel,

if you are using Huawei phone u have something called Hisuit (it is a device manager a default software to manage the phone) for this. I think Samsung phones have something similar if they don't. u can try using other device managers or Hisuit to try an export all your conversation messages.

hope you find what you are looking for all the best,
IT_kid